# FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter showing infinite scroll view while using orderByChild

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, pagination, firebaseui

I want to load data from firebase-database while scrolling. I used `FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter` form firebase-ui. My query is

```java
Query query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Users")
                .child(user.getUid())
                .child("notification")
                .orderByChild("reqTime");
```

But I'm getting infinite scroll view. Removing `orderByChild` shows result as expected. But here I want to load recent data first. Is there any way I can load recent data first using `FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter` ? Or without using `FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter` how can I load recent data  using pagination? Here is my code

```java
PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPrefetchDistance(5)
                .setPageSize(10)
                .build();

        DatabasePagingOptions<BookRequestData> options = new DatabasePagingOptions.Builder<BookRequestData>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(query, config, BookRequestData.class)
                .build();


        mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter<BookRequestData, NotificationViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public NotificationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new NotificationViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.notification_item, parent, false));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NotificationViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final BookRequestData bookRequestData) {
              //other stuffs
           }
            @Override
            protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
                switch (state) {
                    case LOADING_INITIAL:
                    case LOADING_MORE:
                        // Do your loading animation
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                        break;

                    case LOADED:
                        // Stop Animation
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;

                    case FINISHED:
                        //Reached end of Data set
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;

                    case ERROR:
                        retry();
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Without using `orderByChild` it show's
[image: without orderBychild]

using `orderByChild` it show's
[image: using orderBychild]

Comment: would that goes ERROR condition often?

Comment: @RajuyourPepe using `orderByChild` shows data in arbitrary order and infinite scrolling every time.

Comment: How have you solved it? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: I've migrated to Firestore. You can the answer of @Shreyas Patil

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you want to implement but this adapter currently not supports advanced queries as it's already mentioned in documentation.
If you are using queries, adapter will behave like this. This is the problem of this adapter and will try to figure it out. 
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. Documentation mentioned about using orderByKey(), limitToFirst() or limitToLast(). Is there any other way without using this library? I've tried using `((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).setReverseLayout(true)` as it uses pagination just small chunks are reversed.

Comment: Real-time database has some drawbacks like this. If you use Firestore database you can do anything you want. Just migrate to Firestore database.

Comment: I've migrated to Firestore. Thanks for your suggestion.